# "Page Not Found" Error in Facebook for iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook

I have created iOS app having Facebook integrated (which means it also have a page in Facebook). What I have created in app dashboard is a custom section which shows recent likes from iOS app. Now in order to show this custom section of likes collection on the user timeline, the user have to accept it from [this URL](http://www.facebook.com/me/app_%5BAPP_NAMESPACE%5D).

(Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#review

This is profile_section_url).

So I have to redirect user to the `mobile_profile_section_url` from where they click on accept button.

The problem I am getting is that if I open `profile_section_url` (given above) then I am redirected to page which has button `Add to Profile` (which is correct). Since I have to redirect user from my mobile iOS app I have to redirect user to `mobile_profile_section_url` which is like [this](http://m.facebook.com/me/%5BAPP_NAMESPACE%5D).

But I encounter  `Page Not Found` error.